# python regex: string search for a date

Tags: python, regex, search

I am searching for a specific string within a document that will have known words before and after a date, and I want to extract the date. For example, if the substring is "dated as of 29 Jan 2017 to the schedule", I want to extract "29 Jan 2017".

My code is:

```
m = re.search(r'dated as of \w+\s+(.+?)+to the schedule', text, re.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    items["date"] = m.group(1)
```

But - this just gives me "Jan 2017" - it misses the day.

I have tried various variations on the regex search string, but still can't get the day. Any thoughts?

Comment: Replace `(.+?)+to` with `(.+?)\s+to`. You missed a whitespace shorthand.

Comment: Do you have consistent way of how the dates are presented i.e. is it always 01 Jan 2017, 15 Mar 2018, 28 Nov 2019 etc. ?

Comment: No the date is not always in a consistent format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your capturing group (parentheses) not enclose the first part that is captured by `\w+`.

Try mixing capturing group (for the whole part) and non-capturing group for your current parentheses:

```
r'dated as of (\w+\s+(?:.+?)+) to the schedule'
```

As you can see, we have a simple grouping with no repetition that encloses both `\w+` and your previous parentheses.

And your previous parentheses were changed to non-capturing group with `?:` just inside them.

Better yet, your already-existing parentheses and combination of `+?` and `+` doesn't make much sense, so you can just remove it:

```
r'dated as of (\w+\s+.+) to the schedule'
```

Answer (score 0):

"re" module included with Python primarily used for string searching and manipulation

> **\w** = letters ( Match alphanumeric character, including "_")
>
> **\d**= any number (a digit)
>
> **+** = matches 1 or more

```
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

```
import re
data = "dated as of 29 Jan 2017 to the schedule"

match = re.findall(r'\d+ \w+ \d{4}', data)

print (match[0])
```

output:

```
29 Jan 2017
```

Comment: This won't work (and I should have mentioned this in the original post), but the date format won't always be the same. But, the text either side of the date will always be there - I really want to extract what is located in that part of the sentence.

Comment: `\w` includes `alphabets digits and _` so it will match `29 _J_ 2017` too

Answer (score 0):

This works fine :-

```
    text ="dated as of 29 Jan 2017"
    m =re.search(r'\d\d\s(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s\d{4}', 
        text, re.IGNORECASE)
    if m:
        print (m.group(0))
```